# How to bulk add image strip programatically?

Tags: python, photoshop, photos

I have thousands of images. I want to bulk edit them to add a strip containing the Instagram, Facebook and Twitter account usernames at the bottom of the images.

Sample image is here : https://data.whicdn.com/images/254261469/large.jpg

Can the same strip be added programatically preferably using Python .

Comment: You can definitely use Pillow to do this work. Load the image and paste another image into it.. then save. This of course assumes all the social media stuff is identical in all images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you something to start with. The sample below will paste an image into another image using the Pillow/PIL library. It paste a logo image at (25, 25) from the upper left corner of the original image and saves it.

```
from PIL import Image

# Load the image you want to modify
image = Image.open('large.jpg')
print("Image size is ", image.size)

# Load the logo you want to paste in
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
# Decide what size you need possibly based on the first image?
# Here we are just reducing the size so it has a higher chance to fit
logo = logo.resize((logo.size[0] // 4, logo.size[1] // 4))

# Paste the logo into the image
image.paste(logo, (25, 25))

# Save the new image
image.save("test.jpg", format='jpeg')
```

Additional things you need to know:

- The image pasted in must be of the exact size as it appears in the original image. This is why i added the resize code.
- If you are working with images of different sizes you probably need to find a working formula for how to place the new logos. Hopefully they have been added consistently to all images.
- Make sure you read up on the Pillow docs (link below)
- You could end up reducing the image quality when working with jpg images. See the docs for the save method.

http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html